# .NET Core float variable don't print decimals

Tags: c#, .net, ieee-754

I assign `2097151.3` to the float variable and the application prints only the integer part. Possible bug?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float foo = 2097151.3F;

    Console.WriteLine(foo); // prints 2097151

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I'm running a .NET Core console application.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: See precision specs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx - only 7 digits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Floating point numbers have been around since the 1940s. A `float` is only really good for 7 significant figures.

The *nearest* `float` to `2097151.3` is `2097151.25`, and `WriteLine` is clever enough to know that and so it truncates accordingly.

If you want precise *decimal* values then use a `decimal` type.

Comment: So the question is why does `WriteLine` truncate the value, if i´s actually `2097151.25`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Because the "joke" digits are irrelevant and C# is being sensible. You *can* tweak the fomatter to yield all the digits if you must.

Comment: If a float (my float was 2097151.3) only can store 7 digits (2097151), why are you speaking about 2097151.25?

Comment: @Joe Because "7 digits" is only an approximation of what's going on.  Floats can store up to 24 *binary* digits (technically 23, but there's an implicit one you get essentially for free in many cases), which works out to approximately 7 *decimal* digits.